# Event listener firing too early when parameters are passed

Tags: javascript, jquery, parameter-passing, event-listener

I pass a number of parameter to a javascript function which builds a form for the user to fill in.  Among these parameters are two more functions contained in a separate class which handle the saving or canceling of the form.  The cancel function requires two parameters which it uses to determine which list of entities to build.  The problem lies in the parameters.  While in the form building function, if I attached the cancel function to the newly created cancel button without giving it any parameter the function button works fine but builds an empty list due to the lack of parameters.  However if I attach the function with the parameters, the function fires right away when the page is created rather than when the button is clicked.  I have tried attaching the listener in a couple different ways including javascript, jquery and even yahoo.util.  Everything works correctly in the cancel function when it is called with parameters in other instances.  Any ideas on why the function fires to early when parameters are passed?

Here is some sudo code of different ways I have attached the even listener.

```
function buildform(formData, saveFunction, CancelFunction, p1, p2){
      $("#cancelButton").live("click", cancelFunction(p1, p2);
      YAHOO.util.Event.on("cancelButton", "click", cancelFuntion(p1, p2));
      cancelButton.setAttribute("onClick",cancelFunction(p1, p2);
}
```

Comment: You should consistently use `on`, and not use `live`, which is deprecated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to wrap your method calls in function blocks, otherwise they are evaluated immediately:

```
$("#cancelButton").live("click", function () { cancelFunction(p1, p2); });
```